# Local proxy for Azure AD access?

Tags: proxy, azure-activedirectory

A user wants to access an Azure AD secured webservice with an application that is only able to access webservices with basic auth. There is no way to make his application AD compatible and his application runs only on his desktop.

Is there a simple way to give him access to the secured webservice? I was thinking about a proxy program that will be installed on his machine and that tunnels only requests to that specific webservice. So the user would authenticate once and the proxy stores the token and delivers to localhost:80/webservice (the address he configures in his local application).

Comment: "Azure AD secured" isn’t really a thing. Are you perhaps referring to an HTTP API that requires JWT Bearer Token authentication (OAuth 2.0), where the token is expected to be acquired from the Microsoft identity platform?

Comment: @DanielB Yes, that is what I mean, at least I know that we are using OAuth 2.0 tokens and they are provided by Azure AD.